# Access to attribure afterr search (query)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have in route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model(params) {

    let city = params.city_name;
    let cuc = this.store.query('city', {
        linkname: city,
    });


    let itm = this.store.query('product', {
        uriName: params.item_name,
    });

    let dictpage = {
        currentCity: cuc,
        currentProduct: itm,

    };

    return dictpage;
},
```

});

I need get attribute categoryId from cuc, but when i write there:

```
fot(let i in itm){
   console.log(i.id);
}
```

dont work. How to do it?

This i need to find category from good item.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: `fot` should be `for`.

Comment: Yes, but it's a typo. When i try it, i see error!

Comment: What error, does `itm` exist?

Comment: Text error: Error while processing route: product itm.property is not a function model... And white screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it! This code do, what i need:

```
this.store.query('product', {
            uriName: params.item_name
        }).then(function(items) {
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item.get('categoryId'));
            });
        });
```